# MP Chart Android all x axis labels not displayed

Tags: android, charts

I was using android MP Chart library "mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-0" to draw BarChart.I passed 12 months as X axis label for library. But it displays only some of them like Jan ,Apr,jul,Oct. Remaining month values were not displayed. Can any one help me how to display all the Xaxis label values in MP chart Android library for Bar Chart.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `mLineChartView.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(0);`. This will force all of the labels to be displayed.

Comment: "setLabelsToSkip" not available anymore. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setVisibleXRange(float minXRange,float maxXRange);
```

This Limits the maximum and minimum value count that can be viewed by pinching and zooming. e.g. if minRange=10, maxRange=100 then no less than 10 values and no more than 100 values can be viewed at one time without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

mChart1!!.getXAxis().setLabelCount(listdata!!.size)

add size of array to display all labels